# Is $A^2 = A$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I found the eigenvalues as $0$ and $1$. The eigenspaces are then the $NS(A)$ and the $CS(A)$, how do I prove that these spaces provide enough information to chose the correct eigenvectors and form a diagonalizable $A$ ?

Comment: I don't think projections are diagonaliziable, since zero is an eigenvalue.

Comment: No, as a matter of fact I know that it is !! I just dont know how to show it

Comment: A^2 is a projection of A onto the CS(A)

Comment: @SeanRoberson Zero eigenvalues have no relation to diagonalizability. The zero matrix is very diagonalizable.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I was mistaken then - this means I also gave my student some bad information a few weeks ago.

Comment: @SeanRoberson : Certainly projections are diagonalizable.

Comment: I believe that all I need to say is that CS(A) and NS(A) define the basis for R^n and that it contains all the eigenvectors of A and thus A is diagonalizable. Am I right ? @PedroTamaroff

Answer (score 4):

For any $x \in V$, we have $x = Ax + (x - Ax)$.  Now, note that $A (Ax) = Ax$ so $Ax$ is in the eigenspace for $\lambda = 1$; and $A (x - Ax) = 0$, so $x - Ax$ is in the eigenspace for $\lambda = 0$.  This shows that the eigenvectors of $A$ span $V$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$ and $P(X)=X^2-X$. Then, since $P(A)=0$ we have $m(X) \mid X^2-X$.

This shows that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has distinct roots, and hence $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: Do you have any other method to prove the above, I am not familiar with minimal characteristic polynomial solutions and will not be allowed to give that reasoning for my paper !!

Answer (score 2):

You have $A^2 = A.$

If $x$ is in the column space of $A$ then $Ax=x.$ That is because $x = Ay$ for some vector $y,$ so $Ax= A(Ay) = A^2 y = Ay = x.$

If $x$ is *not* in the column space of $A$ then $x-Ax$ is in the null space of $A.$ That is because $A(x-Ax) = Ax-A^2x = Ax-Ax = 0.$

So every vector $x$ can be written as a member of the column space plus a member of the null space, thus: $x = \underbrace{\quad Ax\quad} {}+{} \underbrace{(x-Ax)}.$

This implies every vector can be written as a sum of an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ and an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0.$ In other words, the domain is the direct sum of those two eigenspaces. That means there is a basis of the domain consisting only of eigenvectors. With respect to that basis, the matrix of this linear transformation is diagonal. And every diagonal entry is $0$ or $1.$